# Fixed width for divs (won't resize when window changes width)

Tags: html, css

I have an example of a website for this question (because I can't figure a way to ask it..)

https://livedemo00.template-help.com/opencart_62166/

As you can see, if you resize the browser width, only the margins resizes, and not the divs inside it.

Is there a way to acheive the result in CSS? Do I have to use Javasciprt to achieve that? Thank you.

Comment: You are incorrect that the div elements are not resizing. They most certainly are. div elements are block level elements and by default, they are 100% the width of their parent element, so if the parent element (including the body of the page) resizes, the divs resize to fit. The site also uses responsive images that resize according to the space available.

Comment: You have to be more specific by saying which divs are causing such and such issues... You can't expect someone to just analyze your entire site and give you a proper response

Comment: I don't know how to ask the question... Why so rough...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that example the developers are using media breakpoints. These apply different styles to elements depending on the browser window size. A tutorial is [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)

Basically your CSS looks something like this:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 500px) {
    body {
        width: 800px;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    body {
        width: 300px;
    }
}
```

Comment: *"The lower style code overrides the first style code because it is written further down in the CSS document. CSS is rendered top to bottom."* What? Styles override other styles based on specificity and it is only when specificity is identical will a lower written style override the earlier one. Also CSS is NOT rendered top to bottom - that statement makes no sense.

Comment: Ya i realize how that doesn't make sense. Updated my answer. Wasn't sure the level of understanding the author had of CSS so I was trying to make it as abstracted as possible.